# SQL query to get unique date range from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a query to get location for date from 2 different tables.

Table 1 :

| Start date | End Date | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-06 | 2020-12-31 | New York |

Table 2 :

| Start date | End Date | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-31 | New York |

For the provided date, query will first look in table 1 and see if start date is equal , if not the look in table 2.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: You should considered adding a code showing what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can treat both tables as one virtual table by taking their union:

```
select  Location
from    (select *
         from table1
         union
         select *
         from table2) both
where `Start date` = '2021-01-06';
```

If you don't mind repeating the condition, then applying the condition first on each table separately, and only then making the join, may give a performance gain:

```
select Location
from table1
where `Start date` = '2021-01-06';
union
select Location
from table2
where `Start date` = '2021-01-06';
```